# Which cell is visible when changing UICollectionView layout

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I'm not clear on what cell(s) are visible when changing a UICollecionView layout property.

If a user selects a specific cell, and as a result the layout is changed, what will ensure that the selected cell is still visible?